# ColorFunction for LogPlot (and its cousins)

Tags: plotting, color, logarithmic-scale

I have a `ColorFunction` that I use to color a `Plot`, with the option `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` so that the `ColorFunction` uses the literal x-axis values.

```
f[x_] := Blend[{Blue, Red}, Cos[x]^2];
Plot[x, {x, 0, 4 Pi}, ColorFunction -> (f[#1] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image: Output plot from above code]

I want to modify this code so that it works similarly for a log-scale plot. Specifically `LogLinearPlot`, but a general approach for all of its log cousins would be good. Modifying the above code with the substitution `Plot` -> `LogLinearPlot` produces the error:

[image: Image of error code displayed]

And also a plot, but I don't think the `ColorFunction` has worked properly.

Comment: Maybe using the option `ScalingFunctions`: e.g. instead of `LogLinearPlot` we can use `Plot[x, {x, 0.001, 4 Pi}, ColorFunction -> (f[#1] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ScalingFunctions->{"Log",None}]`?

Comment: @kglr as far as I can tell your suggestion indeed works. Why not make it an answer? Thanks :)

Comment: Tom, posted the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Plot` with the option `ScalingFunctions ->{"Log", None}`:

```
f[x_] := Blend[{Blue, Red}, Cos[x]^2];

Plot[x, {x, 0.001, 4 Pi}, ColorFunction -> (f[#1] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", None}]
```

[image]